# how to set dropdown value by comparing with another attribute in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one dropdown which having type attribute...I want to set value by comparing type and value of  element.

```
<select id="selectId">
      <option type="a" value="1">This is a1</option>
      <option type="b" value="1">This is b1</option>
      <option type="b" value="2">This is b2</option>
      <option type="a" value="2">This is a2</option>
</select>
```

in js, I want to set value as

```
$("#selectId").val(1);
```

but this going wrong...how can I compare type also

Comment: when you want to `$("#selectId").val(1);` , what exact value are you comparing and what all option should get selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare multiple attribute value like below.

```js
var type = "a";
var val = "2";

$("#selectId option[value=" + val + "][type=" + type + "]").prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId">
  <option type="a" value="1">This is a1</option>
  <option type="b" value="1">This is b1</option>
  <option type="b" value="2">This is b2</option>
  <option type="a" value="2">This is a2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution for this
I simply set code as below

```
$('#selectId').find("option[type=a][value=1]").prop('selected', true);
```